# Grid (View) with paging, sorting & searching: How to use Ressource Provider

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, translation, multilingual

we have an architectual problem with our data grid. The grid supports searching, paging and sorting using a linq2entity query, that contains all of the above parameters.

At some pages, the grid should not display the content from the database (e.g. column 'name'), but the translated ressource, loaded by the Resource Provider.

Our Resource Provider gets the translations from the database and caches them to the application cache to avoid unneccessary trips to the database.

At this point, we have the following possibilities:

1. **No searching, sorting and paging on the databse**, so loading all rows, then load the translations from the Resource Provider, then do the searching, sorting and paging at the application.

   *Bad performance, because the database is very big*
2. **Searching, sorting and paging on the database**, then load the ressources for the results.
   *The Displayed Values will not match to the search and sort configuration*
3. **Get the Resources directly from the database**, within the linq query. 
   *The Ressource Provider Caching cannot be used. The Join with the Resource Provider Texts will be very bad and slow*

Every possibility is very bad, but I can't think of another solution. Any good suggestions? How are these problems solved in other software?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by bring the associated filtered records from the database and keep it in `ViewState`.

### How can you improve the Performance?

You can make use of **[JSON / Page Methods](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)** for `Database Callings`. I will explain it to you with the help
of an example.

**[Click here to check the code for GridView Bindings using JSON](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/03/using-jquery-with-client-side-data-binding-templates.aspx)**

### Mark Up With JSON

[image]

I am calling the Code Behind methof from Client side

---

### Code Behind

[image]

### Output

[image]

**[Click here to check the output in case of Update Panels](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/03/using-jquery-with-client-side-data-binding-templates.aspx)**

---

**[Is application is holding too much memory then you need a Doctor like Red Gate Ants Memory Profiler. Click here to see more details about it](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)**

[image]

---

Make sure to use the `Using` Statements to avoid `Memory Out of Exceptions`

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection()) 
{     
      connection.Open();  
      //Also for SqlCommand... Sample code...
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
      { 
      }    
      using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())     
      {         
            transaction.Commit();     
      } 
}
```

---

Are you aware about the `Teleric Grid`? It loads all the records first from the database and keeps in `Cache`. In order to go for this you must use `Paging` and `Disposing` the objects is mandatory. `Teleric Grid` shows these records in `Paging`. Thus you can avoid the rendering issue to get rid of displaying all records in once.

Answer (score 2):

i don't understand your question properly but if you want to all operations on translated resource you have to store translated resource in database then get them in to session object and apply filter on it if it is either in form of table or list then give source to grid which has to configured as work with translated resource which is filtered from session object.

Comment: The problem is, I want to avoid the access to translated ressources within the database (because they won't be cached and the ressource provider should be an own module), but I want to keep the possibilites to filter the grid data within the database.

apperently there is no solution to this, but I'm supprised that this is no common issue... thought this might be a problem for many software systems out there...

Comment: It should be `ViewState` instead of `Session` object.